# Target browser must be a string... (selenium, protractor)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

i have upgraded my environment to have support for my tests for firefox, chrome, etc.

I have installed:

```
Node LTS (6.10.0)
Selenium Server Standalone 3.1.0
protractor@5.1.1
npm@4.1.2
```

When i now want to run my test i receive:

```
    [17:31:32] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
    [17:31:32] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
    [17:31:32] E/launcher - Error: TypeError: Target browser must be a string, but is <undefined>; did you forget to call forBrowser()?
    [...]
    [17:31:32] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100

    Process finished with exit code 100
```

What does that mean?

The config.js is:

```
var TIMEOUT = 10000;
exports.config = {
    ...
    capabilities: [
        {
            'browserName': 'firefox', //tried as 'firefox', firefox and "firefox"
            //'marionette': true //tried true and false
        },
    ],
    ...
};
```

Comment: maybe you are using multiple `capabilities` or another `multiCapabilities`?

Comment: no, the only part i have is that in the description. or is there another place where i can configure this?

Comment: check if you are not instantiating a `WebDriver()` somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was tricky and funny :) You know what .. There is no issue with `browserName`. Problem was you are providing the capabilities object incorrectly. You are providing an array whereas you need to send 1 capabilities object

```
Remove '['  & ']'
```

`capabilities: [{'browserName': 'firefox'},]` - This is incorrect . This means an Array of size 1 with index 0 holding your firefox config

It should be this - `capabilities: {'browserName': 'firefox'}`

Comment: You are a genius, AdityaReddy! Now at least i can start my chrome. But when using firefox i get:
Error: Error: You may not use a custom command executor with the legacy FirefoxDriver

Comment: @StefanieZachmann .. Glad that it worked .. And regarding firefox .. I am not really sure about the latest changes that went with Protractor 5.1.1 but looks like you need to seperate marionette driver now .. I would suggest closing this issue and raising a seperate one which will get an accurate answer

Comment: @StefanieZachmann did you find a solution to the "You may not use a custom command executor with the legacy FirefoxDriver"?